# Password reset issue

Tags: magento-1.9

After recently moving my site, specific users are unable to log in after a password reset. This only happens for specific users and the password does actually reset in the database. Regardless of which way I reset the password, I cannot log in with the new password given. The steps I took:

1. Initiated a password reset through the admin panel / or the user initiated password reset function.
2. Reset the password
3. Checked the database and the password hash had changed to the correct password hash using MD5($salt.$pass)
4. I try to log in and get the invalid username or password message.

The odd thing is that it is only specific accounts that are having this issue, so I possibly thought that it could be to do with a account flag somewhere that is blocking the account.

I would be happy with any input at all as I'm stumped to why it would be specific accounts. If someone could also possibly tell me where the login functions reside, then I an try using `Mage::log` to find the issue throughout the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have found the solution to my own question. For some odd reason, 10/5000 accounts were imported under the wrong store_id and website_id. It was meant to be 1 rather than 0 and that was the reason why those specific users were having issues logging in.